# Getting 0 Scenarios 0 Steps after running the Test Runner file

Tags: junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Below is the Test Runner File

```
    package runner;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;



    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features="D:/InstalledSoftwares/Eclipse_Photon/workspace/March26/src/test/resources/features/login.Feature",
    glue= {"D:/InstalledSoftwares/Eclipse_Photon/workspace/March26/src/test/java/stepDefinitions/LoginSteps.java"})

    public class TestRunner {


    }
```

Below is the Feature File-

```
Feature: Create Account on Facebook

Scenario: Check First Name
Given: User is already on Login Page
When: Enter First Name
And: Enter Last Name
Then: Check if value of First Name is there
```

Below is the Step Definition-

```
package stepDefinitions;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

public class LoginSteps {

@Given("^User is already on Login Page$")
public void User_is_already_on_Login_Page()
{

}
}
```

Below is the Snapshot of Eclipse.
[This is how my Project structures look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q02QO.png)

Comment: your `glue` should be a package name. Just `stepDefinitions` will do.

Comment: Make sure you have a recent version of Cucumber btw.